# Return value from a4j:jsFunction

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I want to get an return value from the a4j:jsFunction. But I don't know how to get this done.

Here's the JSF code:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="createEvent" data="#{calendarController.eventId}" action="#{calendarController.createEvent()}">
        <a4j:param name="eventTitle"
            assignTo="#{calendarController.eventTitle}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

And I call the a4j:jsFunction like this:

```
var id = createEvent(event.title);
```

The Beans method calendarController.createEvent() returns an integer value. The property eventId holds this value to. How can I pass this value back to the javascript code on the page?

Answer (score 3):

As the ajax call is asynchronous you cannot get the value directly from the 'createEvent' method. You can however obtain it if you use the 'oncomplete' attribute for example like this:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="createEvent" data="#{calendarController.eventId}" action="#{calendarController.createEvent()}" oncomplete="alert(data)">
        <a4j:param name="eventTitle"
            assignTo="#{calendarController.eventTitle}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

See [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/176521?_sscc=t) for a similar problem.